# Rails NoMethodError for user but db:migrate isn't helping -updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, haml

I am new to rails and I am trying to add a email confirmation upon register. I currently get this error. I tried rake db:migrate but for some reason I cannot get email_activation_token into the user table. I checked with sqllightbrowser and it's not there.

I am using Haml as you can see below.

**Bonus points**: if you show me how to set email_activation_token to a boolean and make it default it to false.

### NoMethodError in Users#create

> undefined method `email_activation_token' for #(User:0xa2e96cc)

Extracted source (around line #3):

> 3: = edit_email_activation_url(@user.email_activation_token)

I tried this to no avail

> $ rails generate migration add_email_activation_token_to_users

**app/db/migrate/(string)_add_email_activation_token_to_users.rb**

```
class AddEmailActivationTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   add_column :users, :email_activation_token, :string
  end
end
```

**app/config/routes.rb**

```
SomeApp::Application.routes.draw do
 get "password_resets/new"
 get "sessions/new"
 resources :users
 resources :sessions
 resources :password_resets
 get "static_pages/home"
 get "static_pages/help"
 root to: 'static_pages#home'
 match "sign_up",  to: "users#new"
 match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
 match '/log_in',  to: 'sessions#new'
 match '/log_out', to: 'sessions#destroy'
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password
  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}$/
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates :password, :on => :create, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX }
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

### EDIT UPDATE

I got it in the database via

> rake db:rollback
>   rake db:migrate

but now my error is different

> undefined method `edit_email_activation_url' for #(#(Class:0xacca7f4):0xa614ef0)

Comment: what is the output for: "rake db:migrate" and for "cat db/schema.rb" ?

Comment: Pardon? That was unclear. Do you mean what is my view for the user mailer password reset?

Comment: If you go to your terminal and run the commands above, what output/text do you get? Can you paste it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `rake db:migrate:status` and check if the migration in question is already run.

If already run, do `rake db:rollback` which will rollback the last migration.

```
add_column :users, :email_activation_token, :boolean, :default => false
```

Run `rake db:migrate`.

Make sure that the database that you are checking is the database where the migration is running.

Comment: Thank you. Your a gentlemen and a scholar.

Comment: Ok so at least it's added to the database but now i get this error 
undefined method `edit_email_activation_url' for #<#<Class:0xacca7f4>:0xa614ef0>

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in yout `rake db:migrate`
Paste what is coming on after running the `rake db:migrate`

Check your schema_migrations table in your database and check if there exists the time-stamp of your written migration. `(time-stamp)_add_email_activation_token_to_users.rb`.